# Inserting data into database PHP without loading new page

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql

I am struggling with inserting data into my database. The thing is that if I do "form action = "adduser.php" method = "post" then it works. However, it loads a new page and I don’t want that.

```
function addUser() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "adduser.php");
    var formData = new    FormData(document.getElementById("new_person"));
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="addUser()">
   Name: <input id = "new_name" type="text" name = "new_name">
    <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

```
<?php
$conn = pg_connect(******);

$name = pg_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$query = "INSERT INTO highscores (name, score) VALUES ('$name', 200)";

$res = pg_query ($conn, $query);

pg_close();
?>
```

Comment: `<button type="submit"> Submit </button>` => `<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="addUser()" />` also consider looking into jquery. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Change button type and add event to send data to server on click this button:

`<button type="button" onclick="addUser()">Submit</button>`

Answer (score 0):

It loads a new page because you submit the form.
Remove the onsubmit handler from the form and change the button type "submit" to "button".

```
<form id="user" name="user" method="post" action="#">
    <button type="button" onclick="addUser()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Also, why not using jquery ajax, it's much more intuitive : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

See exemple :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your_url',
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    data: $(your_form).serialize(),
    dataType: 'html',
    global: false, // Prevent the global handlers "ajaxStart" from being triggered...
    beforeSend: function() {

    },
    success: function(result, status) {

    },
    error: function(result, status, errno) {

    },
    complete: function(result, status) {

    }
}).done(function() {

});
```